# CSS Problems (Transferring Code From Internal to External File)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently styling my Login and Registration forms with CSS.  I originally used 
an internal style sheet and wrote all of my CSS in there (the CSS and style tags in between the `<head>` tags).  Now, I created a ".css" file and copied all of the CSS from the HTML to the external file sheet.

Now, the problem is that all of the CSS shows, except for the body's background color:

```
body {
        font: 1em/1.62em verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color: #249EC7;
}
```

For some reason, whenever this code is in an internal style sheet, the background color shows, but when I transfer the same code to an external style sheet, it doesn't show. (this is for the Registration form)

The same thing happens with the Login form, but not only does the background color no show, but the padding doesn't show either:

```
<style media='screen'>
body {
        font: 1em/1.62em verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color: #249EC7;
}
form {
        max-width: 58em; 
        padding: .2em; 
        margin: auto; 
        background-color: #648cd1; 
        color: #31d8eb; 
        text-align: center;
} 
form div {
        margin: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
}
form b {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
form b,form input{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 12em;
}
form input {
    padding: 0.25em;
}
h4 a:visited {
    color: #F56433;
}
#logindiv {
    height: 18.5em;
    margin-top: -9.25em;
```

I have no idea what's causing the problem, because I'm literally using the same CSS in both the internal and external style sheets.

Registration Form HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Login & Register System/CSS Files/RegisterFormCSS.css'>
    </head>
<body style='background-color: #249EC7;'>
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <fieldset>
        <h1 style='padding-bottom: .2em;'>Register Now!</h1>
        <div>
            <label for='username'>Username:</label>
            <input type='text' id='username' name='username'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='password'>Password:</label>
            <input type='password' id='password' name='password'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='passwordconfirm'>Re-enter Password:</label>
            <input type='password' id='passwordconfirm' name='passwordconfirm'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='fullname'>First and Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text' id='fullname' name='fullname'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration' style='width: 12em; height: 2.5em; cursor: pointer; background-color: #3E1CE8; color: #FAFAFA; font-size: 1.2em;'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4 style='color: #F5E749;'>Already own a Connection account? Login <a href='index.php'>Here!</a></h4>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Login Form HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en'>
            <head>
                <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device, height=device=height, initial-scale=1'>
            </head>
        <body style='background-color: #249EC7;'>
            <div id='logindiv' style='width: 50%; padding: 10px; border: 5px solid #316ED6; background-color: #648CD1; color: #31D8EB; margin: auto; border-radius: 1.3em; text-align: center;'>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <br />
                <form action='' method='post'>
                    <div>
                        <b>Username:</b>
                        <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px;'/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <b>Password:</b>
                    <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px; '/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type='submit' value='Login' name='login'/>
                        </div>
            </form>
                <div>
                    <h4>No Account? Register <a href='register.php'>Here!</a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy and paste the closing tag in this post, so just pretend that it's there.

Comment: Will you also paste your HTML too?

Comment: Is the "media='screen'" there intentionally? That could be the problem.

Comment: Please post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: can you please put some html to?

Comment: @Ashwin I've now pasted the HTML

Comment: @DanyCode I've now pasted the HTML

Comment: @Elvanos I've put that there to make the CSS friendly to displays.  I'll do print displays in the future

Answer (score 0):

Css have priority, maybe some other rule about the background is overriding the external css. Try to add !important at the end of the property.

Comment: Don't abuse `!important`, find the issue and correct it

Comment: The `!important` didn't work.  Still trying to find the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Just open web developers tools and check properties applied on body.

Comment: Open what web developer tools?

Comment: Google Chrome browser has such a thingy, that allows you to explore CSS properties of elements https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces and '&' from the path of your external CSS file. Replace them with underscores instead. Something like this: "/login_register_system/cssfiles/register_formCSS.css"

Comment: I know that I linked the CSS file properly because almost all of the CSS code appears in the final result.  It's just that a bit of the CSS doesn't show up probably because of an override or something.

Comment: Remove the inline styling of the background-color that you've given to the body element. That should make the DOM pick the property up from the external CSS.